# SQL joins from same table column

Tags: sql, join

Have two tables

- employees: employee_id , employee_name, manager_id, department_id
- departments: department_id,manager_id

I need to show employee id, employee name, manager name, and manager id, yet I cannot figure out how to show manager name. Here is what I have even though it is very wrong and doesn't show the real manager name

```
SELECT e.last_name "Employee", e.employee_id "Emp#", e.last_name "Manager",      
       d.manager_id "Mgr#"
FROM employees e, 
     departments d;
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample .. and the expected  result

Comment: Google 'SQL joins' and follow the simple examples that will easily solve this problem for you.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using keyword Join - Only required use of one table twice

```
SELECT e.last_name "Employee", e.employee_id "Emp#", e2.last_name "Manager", 
       e.manager_id "Mgr#"
       FROM employees e
       JOIN employees e2 ON e2.employee_id = e.manager_id;
```

Or without Keyword Join / using a simple join

```
SELECT e.last_name "Employee", e.employee_id "Emp#", e2.last_name "Manager", 
   e.manager_id "Mgr#"
   FROM employees e, employees e2
   WHERE e2.employee_id = e.manager_id
```

Comment: nice to solve on your own. If you need an extra column from the other table `departments` like `dept_name`, you may add that table with a `left join`, also.

Answer (score 0):

you can do inner join on manager_id so only the matching rows remain

```
 SELECT last_name as "Employee", employee_id as "Emp#", last_name as "Manager", 
   manager_id as "Mgr#"
   FROM employees as e1
   INNER JOIN departments as d2 
   ON e1.manager_id = d2.manager_id;
```